# Object.getOwnPropertyNames when used on object created by generator function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function* generator() {
  yield 'value'
}

console.log(typeof generator()) // object, I double checked :thinking:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(generator())) // prints []
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)) // prints array of methods
```

Why can't I get same for object returned when calling `generator()`? It's supposed to have at least a `next` method.

**UPD**

Due to a @Barmar 's comment, I see why `getOwnPropertyNames` is not returning anyhting. Then I am back to the original questiton, how to get all method/properties of the object created by generator function?

Comment: The generator's methods are inherited from a prototype, they're not "own" properties.

Comment: Try generator().__proto__